# cascading dropdown list with jquery won't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am new to jquery and ajax and I have been trying to populate a list of "agence" based on the "bpr" selected. 
Problem is when I run my application I can see that the data is retrived from the db (sql server) but the list of "agence" remains empty..

here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class SgrController {
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(Model map) {
    return "index";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajoutreclamation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ajoutReclamation(Model model) {

    Reclamation reclamation = new Reclamation();
    model.addAttribute("reclamation", reclamation);
    List<Bpr> bprs = metier.listObject("Bpr");
    System.out.print(bprs.size());
    model.addAttribute("bprs", bprs);
   return "ajoutreclamation";

}
@RequestMapping(value = "/agences", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Agence> agences(
    @RequestParam(value = "bprr", required = true) int idBpr) {
List<Agence> agences = metier.findAgencesByBpr(idBpr);
System.out.println(agences.size());

return agences;
}
...}
```

my jsp page:

```
<form:form method="post" action="ajoutreclamation"
                        commandName="reclamation">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="type-combo">BPR</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <select class="form-control" size="1" name="vbpr" id="bprr">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>--Sélectionnez la BPR</option>
            <c:forEach items="${bprs}" var="bprs">
              <option value="${bprs.idBpr}">${bprs.libelleBpr}</option>
            </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </div>
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="type-combo">Agence</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <select id="agence-combo" id="agc" name="agence" class="form-control" size="1">
      <option value=""></option>                                                    
    </select>
    </div>
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Submit </button>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<c:url var="findAgenceBprURL" value="/agences" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bprr').change(function() {  
            $.getJSON('${findAgenceBprURL}',
                {bprr : $(this).val(),
                 ajax : 'true'},
            function(agences) {
              var html = '<option value="">Agence</option>';
              var len = agences.length;
             for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + agences[i].idAgence + '">'
                + agences[i].libelleAgence+ '</option>';
                                            }
            html += '</option>';
           $('#agc').html(html);
            });
          });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? also try using the done method

Comment: no errors, in the console I can see that the list  agences is not empty

Comment: can you remove one of the id's in your select box as @Jon suggested. since the tag should only have one id and the first id is being given preference here. you can try $('#agence-combo').html(html); instead of $('#agc').html(html); also can you try checking the value of genereated html in the console.log?

Comment: I removed one of the id's (agence-combo) it wasn't there on purpose I must have forgotten to remove it.

Comment: I tried checking the value of html and there's nothing in the console

Comment: so your html is not getting populated. try setting some hardcoded value in $('#agc').html('some hardcoded value') and see if that works. i am guessing that your ajax url is not returning anything.

Comment: nothing displayed :/

Comment: can you try setting a value of agc in the document.ready outside of your $.getJSON method?

Answer (score 0):

Your "agence" select control has two ID properties.

```
<select id="agence-combo" id="agc" name="agence" class="form-control" size="1">
```

`id="agence-combo"` and `id="agc"`

Your JS is referencing `$('#agc')`. You should remove whichever ID you do not intend to use and update the JS accordingly.

Additionally, you have an extra `<option>` closing tag just before you replace the HTML of the select element. You can remove this line: `html += '</option>';`

[EDIT]

Updated code would look like this, provided the correct ID for the select element is agc.

```
<form:form method="post" action="ajoutreclamation" commandName="reclamation">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="type-combo">BPR</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select class="form-control" size="1" name="vbpr" id="bprr">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>--Sélectionnez la BPR</option>
        <c:forEach items="${bprs}" var="bprs">
          <option value="${bprs.idBpr}">${bprs.libelleBpr}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div>
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="type-combo">Agence</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
    <select id="agc" name="agence" class="form-control" size="1">
      <option value=""></option>                                                    
    </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Submit </button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<c:url var="findAgenceBprURL" value="/agences" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bprr').change(function() {  
                $.getJSON('${findAgenceBprURL}', { bprr : $(this).val(), ajax : 'true' }, function(agences) {
                var html = '<option value="">Agence</option>';
                var len = agences.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + agences[i].idAgence + '">'
                    + agences[i].libelleAgence+ '</option>';
                }
                $('#agc').html(html);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been on vacation. Did you get this working? Can you confirm your `$.getJSON` line is retrieving data? I skipped that portion and just created my own array for testing purposes.